# Moxie gwt uploader custom server response

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, moxiemanager

I'm using [Moxie GWT Uploader](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-uploader/showcase/), in my app and its working good.

Server can returns custom JSON object with error and its description.

How I can get, server response object when file upload ends with an error?

Because there is no possibility to get response in **UploadErrorHandler**.

```
uploader.setUploadErrorHandler(new UploadErrorHandler()
  {
     @Override
     public boolean onUploadError( UploadErrorEvent uploadErrorEvent )
     {
        ... 
        return true;
     }
  });
```

Or maybe some opinions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used code from Uploader class and create own Uploader

All than you need is change this method

```
 private boolean uploadSuccessEventCallback( File file, String responseReceived, String serverData ){ ... }
```

changed part:

```
 else
  {
     response = uploadSuccessHandler == null || uploadSuccessHandler.onUploadSuccess(new UploadSuccessEvent(file, serverData, responseReceived));
  }

  return response;
```

Comment: How did you patched this class? Created a new artificact?